# How to factor $x^{4}-22x^{2}+9$ over real numbers?

Tags: polynomials, real-numbers

How do you factor $f(x) = x^{4}-22x^{2}+9$ over real numbers?

I know that over integers it is $(x^2-4x-3)^2$.

Comment: This question is far more specific than what the original title suggested.

Comment: "I know that over integers it is $(x^2-4x-3)^2$." You probably mean that $f(x)=(x^2+4x-3)^2(x^2-4x-3)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $x^4 - 6x^2 + 9 - 16x^2 = (x^2-3)^2 - (4x)^2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $y = x^2$ and factor the resulting quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the quadratic formula gives that the roots of the quadratic
$$x^2 - 4x - 3$$
that appears in your integer factorization are
$$x = 2 \pm \sqrt{7},$$
and since that quadratic is monic, we have
$$x^2 - 4x - 3 = [x - (2 - \sqrt{7})][x - (2 + \sqrt{7})].$$

Squaring both sides gives a factorization of $(x^2 - 4x - 3)^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Substitute $$x^2=t$$

You'll then have a quadratic in t